# Composite Primary Key embedded in attribute JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to declare a composite primary key using the @Idclass annotation.

The primary key for my class is composed of 3 parts, 2 of which are attributes of the class itself, but one of them is 'embedded' in another attribute:

```
@IdClass(value = DivisionPK.class)
public class Division {

private String season;
@Id
private String level;
@Id
private String group;
```

Inside the DivisonPK class, I have declared all the attributes (seasonId, group, and level). How do I, inside the division class, say that season.getId() is the 3rd part of the primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify Season as a key class:

```
@IdClass(value = DivisionPK.class)
public class Division {

   @EmbeddedId
   private Season season;

   @Id
   private String level;

   @Id
   private String group;
}

@Embeddable
public class Season implements Serializable {
  // you fields and code here
}
```